# traverse nested child using ancestry rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, ancestry

I have trying to traverse the child of the node.I have trying things but i am stuck at a point.I have called a function which traverses the node and all its children but i want to store that in a variable or a collection so i can display them one by one.This is the function.

```
module MessagesHelper
    def nested_comments(comments)
    comments.map do |comment, sub_comments|
       render(comment) + content_tag(:div, sub_comments, :class => "nested_comments")
     end.join.html_safe
   end
end
```

This is the controller file

```
def index
     @messages = Message.all

  end
```

This function is called in index.html.erb.

```
<div class="Pages index">
   <h2>Messages</h2>

   <%= link_to("Add new Page",{:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

      <%= nested_comments @messages.arrange(:order => :likes) %>

          </div>
```

This displays result in this form.

```
{#<Message id: 5, content_title: "2-2", content: "eeer", likes: 67, created_at: "2015-01-15 11:32:38", updated_at: "2015-01-15 11:32:38", ancestry: "1/3">=>{}, #<Message id: 6, content_title: "qqq", content: "asa", likes: 129, created_at: "2015-01-15 11:33:10", updated_at: "2015-01-15 11:33:10", ancestry: "1/3">=>{#<Message id: 7, content_title: "jjjjhjjggjgj", content: "hjhjhjhj", likes: 90, created_at: "2015-01-15 17:01:02", updated_at: "2015-01-15 17:01:02", ancestry: "1/3/6">=>{}}}
```

Now this stores all the result in a single collection i want to traverse them one by one or store it in a variable How do i do that?

Comment: do not use `arrange`

Comment: but then it would simply traverse and display without arranging in form of parent-child relation..i want to traverse in this form  parent-child1-grandchild1 etc

Comment: then undo the created hash :) actually either you get children and order them yourself, or you ask ancestry to do it for you but then you have to work with the resulting hash and make it an array